# How do I displayed Json into a text view with correct identation in cocos2d/cocos2dx?

Tags: json, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

When I try to show the JSON string, the indentation is gone and very ugly.

Is there a way to make it look better?

Comment: Do you have any code at all to show?

Comment: and maybe a screen shot of "ugly" with your criteria for goodness maybe.

Comment: The Json format looks good when it's displayed in a browser,sorry the code is not available now as I am off the office now..

Answer (score 0):

As you stated in a comment : the JSON string looks good in a browser. That is propably (I'm 99% sure) because most browsers will recognize the content as JSON and display it nicely, in an easier to read form. But in its core, the JSON string is just a set of characters, without any special whitespace characters like `/n` or `/t` to indicate newlines or tabs.

So to answear your question : in order to display your JSON string similarily to what you see in your browser, you'd have to parse and format it yourself.

If you are using a CCLabel to display it, you could subclass it creating a JSONLabel which would format a string given in its constructor the way that you like it.